# converting customer input from Anonymous Customer to Contact in NetSuite

Tags: record, netsuite

Our contact page includes a NetSuite Case form which allows us to direct workflows to the proper department within our company (i.e. warranty, sales, etc.). However, NetSuite does not create contacts with this information, opting instead to keep them all in "Anonymous Customer". However this makes things difficult if we need to bring the person into the system as a new customer or potential lead.

Is there any way to convert info submitted by a user online via a case form into a contact?

Answer (score 1):

NetSuite creates a new anonymous customer if the company submitted in the case form doesn't exist or if the company is not submitted. If you have the `Company Name` field added to your form and the form is submitted with an existing Company name, a new contact is created for that company. You can also pass the company name by parameter in the url using `&companyname=mycompany` and a new contact will be created in that company with the information submitted in the case form.

Comment: that's interesting but probably won't work in our case, as we have many individuals who are customers.